# Next.js attempts to parse MDX files as plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, next.js, mdxjs, next.js14

I'm building a website using Next.js with (local) MDX files for content. Whenever I add a .MDX file to my source tree and try to navigate to it, Next.js throws a parsing error either after '#' signs (`# Heading`), the front-matter, or JSX content. It simply attempts to interpret the file as plain JavaScript and fails.

I'm using Next.js version 14.0.4 and have installed the following dependencies:
`@next/mdx @mdx-js/loader @mdx-js/react @types/mdx gray-matter`

```json
"@mdx-js/loader": "^3.0.0",
"@mdx-js/react": "^3.0.0",
"@next/mdx": "^14.0.4",
"@types/mdx": "^2.0.10",
"gray-matter": "^4.0.3",
```

Here's my `next.config.js`:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'mdx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
    reactStrictMode: true,
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

This is the file I'm trying to parse:

```markdown
---
Title: Test Post
---

# This is just a test post

Hello!
```

The error messages I get look like this:

```markdown
Module parse failed: Assigning to rvalue (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

I've installed the MDX loader as per the [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/mdx). I have also tried the following `next.config.js`, but the errors remained:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'mdx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
    webpack: (config, {defaultLoaders}) => {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: '/\.mdx$/',
            use: [
                defaultLoaders.babel, {
                    loader: '@mdx-js/loader'
                }
            ]
        });
        return config;
    }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out, the issue was the config file. I wasn't importing `withMDX` from the `@next/mdx` package and wrapping the config object in it.

Here's the corrected version:

```js
const withMDX = require('@next/mdx')();

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'mdx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
    reactStrictMode: true,
}

module.exports = withMDX(nextConfig);
```

Note that it doesn't work without the `()` at the end of the `require` statement.